# Creating cron jobs via Dockerfile

Tags: docker, cron, debian

I'm having some issues with trying to setup and run some cron jobs through Docker - it could have something do do with the base image I'm using, but I'm not sure and I'm a bit confused with it all.

Below is what my Dockerfile looks like:

```
FROM wordpress:php7.1-apache

# Remove wp image cache
RUN rm -rf /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/opcache-recommended.ini \
&& apt update \
&& apt install wget -y \
&& apt-get -y install cron

ADD ./docker/local/crontab /etc/cron.d/mycron
RUN chmod +x /etc/cron.d/mycron
RUN crontab /etc/cron.d/mycron
RUN service cron reload
RUN service cron restart

COPY ./wp-config.php /var/www/html/wp-config.php
COPY ./.htaccess /var/www/html/.htaccess
COPY ./theme /var/www/html/wp-content/themes/paper

RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www
```

When I build this image with docker-compose, everything works fine, website works perfectly. However the cron jobs aren't running. If I log into the container and type `crontab -l`

It lists out the cron jobs exactly as per the `mycron` file

```
* * * * * root wget -O- "http://url.to/script/file.php" >> /var/log/script1.log
* * * * * root wget -O- "http://url.to/script/file2.php" >> /var/log/script2.log
```

But the cron jobs do not run. And the log files aren't created.

However when I type in `crontab -e` and change nothing then save and exit, then type in `service cron restart`

The cron jobs start running and the log files are created.

Comment: have you try adding `service cron restart` command in your `ENTRYPOINT` and check the log file status is it working or not ?

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue, any updates?

Comment: @ccalderon911217 I've just a answered as best I can.. but I did get it working..

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so I fixed it by doing the following - no idea whether it is the right way or not...

The end of my Dockerfile looks something like this..

```
ADD ./docker/local/mycron /etc/cron.d/mycron
COPY ./docker/local/all.env /root/all.env

ADD ./docker-entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin/init.sh
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/init.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["init.sh"]
CMD ["apache2-foreground"]
```

Then, At the top of the (docker-entrypoint.sh file) - now init.sh

```
chmod +x /etc/cron.d/mycron
crontab /etc/cron.d/mycron
service cron reload
service cron restart
chmod +x /var/www/html/path.to.cron.sh
```

With the cron file looking something like

```
0,30 * * * * /var/www/html/path.to.cron.sh
```

If you have issues with environment variables not existing, it's because the crontab is executed under a different environment, so you need to execute the cron by passing in an environment var file with it, by prefacing with a period to mean, 'execute with'.

```
0,30 * * * * . /root/all.env; /var/www/html/path.to.script.php
```

Make sure you set the correct timezone, not just on hour host server, but also inside the containers as well.

It's probably slightly over complex, but, it works for me. Let me know if you have any questions..

Comment: Thanks, I had fixed it yesterday by adding 
crontab /path/to/crontab